# Authorize.net for Magento throwing "unable to read response or response is empty"

Tags: magento, magento-1.6, authorize.net

We have a 1.6 Magento site that is sending out "Payment Transaction Failed" emails. The server is throwing the error "unable to read response or response is empty". We are using the Authorize.net payment gateway. It's been working just fine and there have been no changes to the site. What could be causing this error?

Comment: Who is sending the emails? Authnet? Or Magento? Is it possible to see what your request to Authnet looks like? And response, too?

Comment: Magento is sending out the email. It's the generic something-went-wrong-with-payment email.
I do not have the request or response logs.

Answer (score 1):

This error message, exception, is thrown here **Zend_Http_Client** around line **993**
If you take a look at the code, it means that the response could not be read, possibly because of a timeout, network glitch or something like that.

Here is the code snippet

```
$response = $this->adapter->read();
if (! $response) {
    /** @see Zend_Http_Client_Exception */
    #require_once 'Zend/Http/Client/Exception.php';
    throw new Zend_Http_Client_Exception('Unable to read response, or response is empty');
}
```